# Downloading old version app on android

Tags: android, cordova

I have android app, i use phonegap 1.2.
To create apk file, i just zip `www` folder, next i pload archive to https://build.phonegap.com/apps/
Than i download apk file from phonegap.com and upload it to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

Than i saw this message (play.google.com):

```
Warning: Active APKs support fewer devices than previously active APKs. Some users will not receive updates.
```

When I run *Play* on my android phone, there wasn't any updates for my app. So i removed my app and download it once again, nothing has change. I just downloaded the old version.

Why do i getting this warning? How can i make it works so users who already download this app could see updates?

**Update**

I removed one icon in main menu, thats all. Here is code i have change:

```
      if(cc_maps == 1){
        $('<li><a href="#gmap"><img src="images/icons/map.png" alt="map" width="75" height="75" /></a></li>').appendTo('#cc_homeicons');        
      }
```

changed to:

```
      /*if(cc_maps == 1){
        $('<li><a href="#gmap"><img src="images/icons/map.png" alt="map" width="75" height="75" /></a></li>').appendTo('#cc_homeicons');        
      }*/
```

Also i have changed phonegap to 1.2 (it was 1.1 before) but i get this error in 1.1. I though it was the reason, thats why i change it.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this is that the changes you have made in your apps require the use of features that are available on less devices than the previously used features. If you told us what changes you made, we could elaborate on this.